# Encrypt PayPal Button for Any PayPal Account - Your Account and Accounts Other Than Your Own

Tags: php, encryption, dynamic, paypal, accounts

Is there a way to dynamically encrypt PayPal buttons for multiple PayPal accounts other than your own?

I've created a marketplace so to speak, and I'm currently encrypting all buttons using my public key that I uploaded to PayPal.

However, it looks like PayPal will not let the transaction go through if a button has been encrypted with a business email address that is not the one that matches the account where the public key certificate was uploaded.  I get this error message with my current setup:

```
We were unable to authorize the transaction. Please contact your merchant.
```

So, I looked at adaptive payments, but it looks pretty complicated and not exactly what I want to do anyways.  I really just want a simple payment going directly between the buyer and one of my market place users (the seller) with an IPN capturing the details of the transaction.  Is this possible to encrypt, or should I just use standard unencrypted PayPal buttons for my users' PayPal business email address? My IPN checks to make sure the right amount is received.

Is there an easy way to do what I'm asking using PHP?  Can someone point me in the right direction / provide an example?  I wonder why PayPal won't let me do what I'm trying to do.  The button was encrypted, so why is it considered unacceptable to set a different receiver email address?

Most of the examples I've seen for adaptive payments don't make much sense. I just need something simple.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this answers your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610932/how-to-better-integrate-paypal-buy-now-button-for-3rd-party-sellers